# Microsoft Graph API to extract a .pst

Tags: python, java, microsoft-graph-api, exchange-server

We have a use case here to extract a .pst file of a given user using MS Graph API. we are able to do it through PowerShell commands provided by MS. but now want to move away from PS scripts and create a solution using Java/Python. But, unfortunately, I don't see any APIs available from Microsoft to do a mailbox extraction. These extractions are mostly for O365 mailboxes.

Looking something equivalent to this command - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/new-mailboxexportrequest?view=exchange-ps

Any guidance or pointers here to any documentation will be much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing PST specific in Graph or EWS. It is a purely client side file format. There are some libraries that lets you access PST files, but your mileage will vary greatly.

You can create a PST file using Extended MAPI (you will need to add/edit a profile and add/configure the MSUPST MAPI service), but that requires C++ or Delphi. If using [Redemption](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption) is an option (it supports any language including Python, I am its author), it will let you create a PST file using [RDOSession](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm).`LogonPstStore`. You can then create folders and messages in the PST file, and import data ([RDOMail](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOMail.htm).`Import`) in just about any format, including MIME. If you are working with Exchange, it will let you work with the Fast Transfer Stream format - it is native to Exchange (use [ExportItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/exportitems-operation) EWS operation) and, unlike MIME, preserves all MAPI-specific properties.